# Is this book extract good grammar?

Tags: grammar

> 全身から**金持ち光線と金持ちを優先しろ**光線をびんびん出していた。
>   From her whole body there radiated out a rich person beam and a "prioritise rich people!" beam.

I understand what the author is saying but is this good grammar?

For example the object of 優先する seems to be 金持ち光線と金持ち i.e. "prioritise rich people beams **and** rich people". What is going on with the と here?

Also, there seems to be something missing between 優先しろ and 光線. My instinct as a learner is to insert a という here. Would that be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this sentence looks natural, although it's far from formal.

First, she's emitting two kinds of beams simultaneously, 金持ち光線 ("(I-am-a-)rich-person beam") and 金持ちを優先しろ光線 ("(you-must-)prioritize-rich-people beam"). The object of 優先しろ is only 金持ち just before it.

As you already know, the imperative form does not usually directly modify a noun as a relative clause. Saying 金持ちを優先しろという光線 ("a beam saying 'Prioritize a rich person!'") would make this sentence look more "formal", but it makes the sentence much less humorous at the same time. Formality is undesirable in a joking expression like this. If I'm not mistaken, [`"prioritise rich people!" beam` is a slangy expression, too, and thus can convey a similar tone](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/84298/80278).

Other examples of nonstandard ways of modifying a noun include: [歩け歩け運動](https://www.city.oyama.tochigi.jp/kyoikuiinkai/supo-tu/aruke25.html), [貸します詐欺](http://www.city.tomisato.lg.jp/0000001409.html), [ほんまでっか!?TV](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%9B%E3%83%B3%E3%83%9E%E3%81%A7%E3%81%A3%E3%81%8B!%3FTV). "歩くことを促進する運動" or "ほんまでっかと問いかけるTV" would sound far less attractive to me.